# Pointwise convergence but the integral limits do not line up

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A question I've been staring at for hours is asking me the following: let $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. Find $f_n, f\in\Sigma^+(S,\Sigma)$ such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise as $n\to\infty$ and it holds that
$$\int f d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n d\mu = \infty,$$
but at the same time there exist $E\in\Sigma$ such that
$$\int_E f d\mu \neq \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_E f_n d\mu.$$

I've been racking my brain over this, but nothing I come up with works. If $E$ is a measure 0 set, then both integrals are 0. If $E$ is such that $\int_E f d\mu<\infty$ the equality holds in general. So what I'm thinking is that I need to find $E$ such that $\int_E f d\mu=\infty$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_E f_n d\mu<\infty$. I've had no luck with this though. Anybody got an example that works?

Answer (score 2):

$f_n=n1_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$ and $f=0$ on $(0,1)$, $f_n=f=1$ on $\mathbb R \setminus (0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

On $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure take the sequence
$$ f_{n}(x)=\cases{\frac{1}{|x|} \quad |x|>1 \\
0 \quad 1\geq |x|>\frac{1}{n}\\
\frac{1}{|x|} \quad |x| <\frac{1}{n} }$$

This sequence of functions converge pointwise to a function with $\int_{(0,1)}f=0$ but $\int_{(0,1)}f_n=+\infty$ for all $n$.